# How can I get a piece of text scanned and have all hyperlinks "behind the text" replaced with HTML attribute tags?

Tags: php, javascript, html, text, hyperlink

I currently have a page which consists of HTML, CSS, and PHP. Basically this is an administrator page for one of my websites which will be posting information found from other websites. Basically, I need a code block(Whether that is PHP or Javascript I really don't care) which will automatically search through the text, find any links, and convert those links into  tags with the link text within them. I have been researching for a long time on how to accomplish this, but can't seem to find anything that specifically applies to my situation.

To review what I am trying to say in a more basic way: I have an admin page that has several inputs and a textarea. I want a block of code to check the text within the textarea and find all links, and replace them with a Link Text tags. The reason I need it to work like this is because I consistently will be pasting text which has links included in it already.

As an example, I would want this text..

[Google](http://google.com)

automatically replaced with..

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
```

I would prefer the solution consist of PHP only, but if I have to, I will not mind working with Javascript somewhat.

**EDIT:**

Basically all I had to do was paste this Script in my  tag within my HTML:

`<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script> <script> tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'}); </script>`

This automatically converts textarea tags to the "rich" editor which functions the same as a textara, but works much better! I Hope this is useful to others!

Comment: Uhm..so you want to transform a link into..a link?

Comment: Or do you want to copy `link texts` from anywhere on the internet and automatically convert it to a link? (For instance, copy the title of this question from the browser and replace that with the link?) That's an impossible thingo. (unless, you want to replace obvious texts such as google, facebook, and things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textarea alone cannot do this. You need to use a JavaScript-based text-editor such as [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [cKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/http://) unless you want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-invent the wheel"?

Comment: There are text editors that ALREADY do what you want, so why bother writing a NEW text editor.

Comment: Can I treat that editor on tinyMCE as a regular textarea? I tried using it, but it is not allowing me to edit an article like I could have when I was using a normal textarea.

Comment: tinyMCE replaces your textarea with its own code-managed editor. If you are having difficulties, post a new question relating to that.

Comment: I have figured out what my problem was. Thanks for the help Diodeus. :)

Comment: @user2569806 And what was the problem? And how did you solve it? Otherwise this question won't be of any help for future users

Comment: Basically all I had to do was paste this Script in my <head> tag within my HTML:

<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>

This automatically converts textarea tags to the "rich" editor which functions the same as a textara, but works much better! I Hope this is useful to others!